# Getting an error using Promise.all in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, es6-promise

I've been using axios.get for my api requests, but I was testing out how to pull multiple api requests in on componentDidMount.  I have been looking this up and using other peoples code, and decided that Promise.all is the way to go.  I definitely could be wrong, and don't mind going back to axios for this.  Using the axios.spread method was throwing an error, and Promise.all is throwing the same error as well.  Any ideads on why this isn't working?

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import axios from 'axios'
import { Table } from './Table'

export class DataList extends React.Component {

    state = {
        articles: [],
        google: []
    }
    componentDidMount() {
        Promise.all([
            ('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/portblog/'),
            ('http://www.google.com')
        ])
        .then(([res, googleRes]) => {
            this.setState({
                articles: res.data,
                google: googleRes
            })
            console.log(res.data)
        })
    }
    render() {
        return(

            <div>
            <Table key={this.state.articles.id} 
                   articles={this.state.articles} />
            </div>
        )
    }
}
export default DataList
```

Edit: Error:

```
DataList.js?a7e0:29 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined
```

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: DataList.js?a7e0:29 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this out. I don't see you sending ajax requests to those URLs.

```
    Promise.all([
        axios.get('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/portblog/'),
        axios.get('http://www.google.com')
    ])
```

Comment: Solid!  This fixed it kind sir, here in five minutes I will mark as answered.  You answered it so fast stackoverflow needs time to catch it!  Thanks Mr. Aaron!